# How to chain completions?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, completionhandler

What is the best way to chain completions in Swift? I'm using network library that fetches some information from API. To fetch information I need:

Authorize -> Get list of categories -> Get list of forums -> Get list of topic ->

Nested completions is looking awfully, is any way to do it better? I've tried to work with dispatch_sync, but haven't got luck.

Example code:

```
    api.get_session_key(self.credentials) { (sessionKeyResult) -> () in
        switch sessionKeyResult {
        case .Success(let sessionKey):
            // STEP 2

            self.api.list_categories(self.credentials.userLogin, completion: { (surveysResult) -> () in
                switch surveysResult {
                case .Success(let surveys):

                    // STEP 3 and so on

                case .Error(let error): completion(synced: Result.Error(error))
                }
            })

        case .Error(let error):
            completion(synced: Result.Error(error))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my point of view, you have at least 3 options:

1. [Facebook Bolts](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-ObjC) framework
2. Any `Functional Reactive Programming` framework like [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift)  or [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa)
3. `NSOperation`

I would suggest you to consider them in this order :)

`FB Bolts` has smallest overhead and IMHO suits best for such simple task like chaining operations. It's written in Objective-C but works well also with Swift.

`Functional Reactive Programming` concept is great but forces you to reconsider your application architecture again and do some refactor probably. If you do, chaining operation will be easy and very elegant, specially in Swift. You will also find that many tasks, for example asynchronous operations can be done much simpler then in imperative way.

`NSOperation` for me has too big overhead. It looks great at first glance, but when you start coding you will crash about many things like passing parameters between certain operations or elegant error handling.

Answer (score 2):

Use NSOperation and NSOperationQueue. This makes it easy for successful completion of one asynchronous operation to be a prerequisite for starting another, and so on to any desired length and in any desired configuration.